# How does SharedPreferences value retrieval work "under the hood"

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Shared preferences are stored as key-value pairs inside an xml file. That's a fact. 
I haven't been able to find any documentation on the batter but ... when trying to find and load the value of a certain key, how does it actually look for the key inside the xml? Does it load the entire xml file into memory and then searches for the key or does it use some other method which is more memory friendly to go through each key?

I've come across an app which stores a ton of key-value pairs in shared preferences instead of using a database (there's A LOT!) and it is my hunch that this is quite memory intensive, as it will load the entire file into memory just to retrieve the specific item.

Can anyone clarify how this works "under the hood" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it load the entire xml file into memory and then searches for the key...?

Yes, at least in [the standard implementation](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java). Technically, `SharedPreferences` is an interface, but AFAIK `SharedPreferencesImpl` is the implementation that `Context` uses for methods like `getSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Never though of actually looking in the source code :) Thanks. So yeah ... time to do some code refactoring ... sigh

Comment: that is not correct, it will load the entire file upon instantiation and then hold the values in a HashMap, retrieving values does not cause the file to be reloaded

Comment: @lelloman: "it will load the entire file upon instantiation" is the same as "Does it load the entire xml file into memory and then searches for the key". I will adjust the portion of the quote in my answer, rather than including the full sentence, to clear up any confusion.

Comment: What I mean is that it won't load the file just to retrieve a single key, which is the OP concern as far as I can understand, and using a database instead doesn't sound necessarily like a better solution. Using a db could mean 2 things, a) the table is cached in memory, so it's memory-intensive anyway or b) every time you want to retrieve a key you have to do a file read, which is slow. I just wanted to be clear that there might be a performance benefit in using SharedPreferences over a db

Answer (score 2):

If you're curious about an implementation of SDK classes you can download the sources directly with Android Studio. You can than hold ctrl and left-click on an SDK class and jump directly into the code, or even find usages and look for classes by name. If you've never done it I would really recommend it, it's super convenient.

As for the specific question, `SharedPreferencesImpl` (as pointed out by CommonsWare is the implementation of `SharedPreferences` returned by `Context`) only loads the file in the constructor and when the file changes. When reading values the performance should then be very close to reading directly from a `HashMap`

If you're writing though, it will write the *entire file* when you call `apply` or `commit` on `Editor`, but using `apply` will do that asynchronously.